# declaring variable in implementation (.m) file

Tags: objective-c

If my implementation file looks like below

```
int someIntVariable;

@implementation SomeClass

- (void) foo {
    someIntVariable = 0;
}

@end
```

What is the behaviour of `someIntVariable`. Is it static to this implementation class or instance level? and how is it accessible outside the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `someIntVariable` is defined outside of the `@interface` (which you haven’t included here), that means that it is not an instance variable. It's a global.

And because you omitted the `static` keyword, it means that this variable is technically available to any other compilation unit, though they'd have to define their own `extern` reference to it:

```
extern int someIntVariable;
```

If you wanted to prevent that, i.e. make this private to this particular compilation unit, you'd include the `static` keyword in the original declaration of `someIntVariable` in `SomeClass.m`:

```
static int someIntVariable;
```

---

Note, you've defined this global variable outside of the `@implementation`. But it's worth noting that the above still applies if it was inside the `@implementation`, too. It exhibits the exact same behavior as your example (a global variable, not a instance variable, that other compilation units could manipulate without your knowledge) if it was inside the `@implementation`:

```
@implementation SomeClass

int someIntVariable;

- (void) foo {
    someIntVariable = 0;
}

@end
```

Bottom line, if you wanted static behavior but wanted to make sure it couldn't be manipulated by external compilation units, you'd declare it to be a `static`, as shown above. And obviously, if you want an instance variable, you'd declare this in the `@interface` (either explicitly declare instance variable or, more common now, declare property and let the compiler synthesize the ivar for you).

Comment: And of course if the OP wants a private instance variable, they can do: `@implementation { int someInVariable }`.

Comment: Yep, that works, too. I'd generally still define private instance variables inside the `@interface` of a private class extension, but including it in braces in the `@implementation` works, too.